# $\sum_{j=1}^n \psi(\lambda_j)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \triangle \psi(z) \log|P(z) | \ dm(z)$

Tags: complex-integration, residue-calculus, greens-theorem

Let $$P(z)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-\lambda_i) $$  $$\psi\in C_c^2(\mathbb{C}) $$ how do we get $$\sum_{j=1}^n \psi(\lambda_j)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \triangle \psi(z) \log|P(z) | \ dm(z)$$where $\triangle$ is the Laplacian, $m$ is the Lebsgue measure on $\mathbb{C}$. The author metioned that it is just an application of Green's theorem.

Source: Circular law for the sum of random permutation matrices https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejp/1524880977 Section 2

Comment: Please mention which textbook, chapter you are using and have found this text.

Comment: Thank you I will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows by 2 applications of Green's theorem, and is essentially a classical result in the basic theory of PDEs.  Namely that in dimension 2, the solution to the Poisson equation
$$ \Delta u = \psi$$
 for $\psi \in C^2_c(\mathbb R^2)$ is
$$ u(x) = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb {R}^2} \psi(z)\log|z-x| \, dm(z).$$ 
Its usually proven by "integration by parts" i.e. Green's theorem twice, each time transferring one gradient in $\Delta = \nabla\cdot\nabla$ to the logarithm, but you have to either develop some distribution theory or be careful with the behavior at 0 by cutting out a small ball around $0$ and then taking a limit. 
This is done in Evans around page 20, [Green's Function for 2D Poisson Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152385/greens-function-for-2d-poisson-equation), [these](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/greensfcns.pdf)  set of notes, or [these](http://math.lsa.umich.edu/~sijue/greensfunction.pdf) other set of notes.

The danger when blindly integrating by parts is that $\Delta \log|z| = 0$ everywhere where this function is defined, but it doesn't integrate the same as the 0 function. As a distribution, its more correct to say that $\frac1{2\pi}\Delta \log|z|$ is the unit Dirac mass  at 0.

Now note that we can write starting from the right-hand side,

$$ \text{RHS} = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R^2} \Delta \psi(z) \sum_{j=1}^n \log|z-\lambda_i| dm(z) = \sum_{j=1}^n \Delta u(\lambda_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n \psi(\lambda_i),$$
Which is the left-hand side. The Laplacian $\Delta$ went through the integral onto $\psi$ as a general property of convolutions; the 1D analogue is $(f*g)' = (f')*g = f*(g')$, and the same holds in higher dimensions.